# Show/hide list elements with multiple possibilities

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, frontend

I do have a long list of links with multiple classes and checkbuttons to show and hide them. The classes are based in two categories: occupation and countries. My solutions was build first with occupation only, which is easy: get the class and show/hide it. But that changed with the second dimension, the countries.

Now some links which are not displayed come back again, like uncheck america, but if a occupation is checked back again, the country is displayed again, even if the country is not.

**What would be the best solution to check if a link is already not displayed and to not let it come back again?** *Edit: ok, I understand now that I do need a new approach since my code is far to simple for more than one dimension. If there is a small plugin-solution for my problem I would also use it!*

For eventual better comprehension a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tcsf76b4/2/

Thanks in advance!

My html:

```
<div class="modal-content">

        <div class="buttons-list">
            <label class="checkcontainer">Sozial
                <input name="social" id="socialButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeSocial">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Sport
                <input name="animal" id="sportButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeSport">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Tier- &amp; Umweltschutz
                <input name="animal" id="animalButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeAnimal">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Medizin
                <input name="medical" id="medicalButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeMed">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Schule/KiTa
                <input name="child" id="childButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeChild">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Specials
                <input name="special" id="specialButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeSpecial">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <hr>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Afrika
                <input name="africa" id="africaButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeAfrica">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Amerika
                <input name="america" id="americaButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeAmerica">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Asien
                <input name="asia" id="asiaButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeAsia">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Europa
                <input name="europe" id="europeButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeEurope">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="checkcontainer">Ozeanien
                <input name="oceania" id="oceaniaButton" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="includeOceania">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <ul class="projektliste_wrap">


                            <li class="social albanien europe projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Albanien/albanien-einrichtung-fuer-menschen-mit-behinderung" target="_blank">
                        Albanien - Einrichtung für Kinder und junge Erwachsene mit Behinderung                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="social europe albanien projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Albanien/albanien-nurserycare" target="_blank">
                        Albanien - Krankenhaus in Tirana (Nursery Care)                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="social europe albanien projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Albanien/albanien-roma-center" target="_blank">
                        Albanien - Community Center für Roma-Kinder in Tirana                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="animal europe albanien projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Albanien/albanien-tierheim" target="_blank">
                        Albanien - Tierheim in der Nähe von Tirana                    </a>
                </li>


                            <li class="special america argentinien projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien/cordoba-praktikum" target="_blank">
                        Argentinien - Praktika (Beispiele)                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="social america argentinien projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien/cordoba-projektliste" target="_blank">
                        Argentinien - Unterrichten an einer Sprachschule                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="animal america argentinien projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien/cordoba-reittherapie" target="_blank">
                        Argentinien - Reittherapie mit Kindern nahe Córdoba                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="social america argentinien projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien/cordoba-sozialarbeit" target="_blank">
                        Argentinien - Soziarbeit mit Kindern in Córdoba und Umgebung                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="sport america argentinien projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien/cordoba-sportprojekte" target="_blank">
                        Argentinien - Sportprojekte in Córdoba und Umgebung                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class=" projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien-buenos-aires/Galerie" target="_blank">
                                            </a>
                </li>
                            <li class=" projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien-buenos-aires/buenosaires-projektliste" target="_blank">
                                            </a>
                </li>
                            <li class=" projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien-buenos-aires/buenosaires-projektliste_gemeinde" target="_blank">
                                            </a>
                </li>
                            <li class=" projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien-buenos-aires/buenosaires-projektliste_gesundheit" target="_blank">
                                            </a>
                </li>
                            <li class=" projektliste">
                    <a href="https://auszeitstaging.azurewebsites.net/Freiwilligenarbeit/Argentinien-buenos-aires/buenosaires-projektliste_kinder" target="_blank">
                                            </a>
                </li>
    </div>
```

My js:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    var socialToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('social'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('socialButton').onclick = socialToggle;

    var sportToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('sport'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('sportButton').onclick = sportToggle;

    var animalToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('animal'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('animalButton').onclick = animalToggle;

    var medicalToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('medical'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('medicalButton').onclick = medicalToggle;

    var specialToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('special'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('specialButton').onclick = specialToggle;

    //Länderfilter

    var africaToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('africa'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('africaButton').onclick = africaToggle;

    var americaToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('america'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('americaButton').onclick = americaToggle;

    var asiaToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('asia'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('asiaButton').onclick = asiaToggle;

    var europeToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('europe'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('europeButton').onclick = europeToggle;

    var oceaniaToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('oceania'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('oceaniaButton').onclick = oceaniaToggle;

    var elseToggle = function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (lis[i].classList.contains('none'))
                if (lis[i].style.display === 'none') lis[i].style.display = '';
                else lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
```

and the css:

```
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.buttons-list {
    padding: 0 0 1rem;
}

.checkcontainer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 1.1rem .5rem 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.checkcontainer input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.checkcontainer:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #00a4e9;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.checkcontainer input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #00a4e9;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.checkcontainer input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.checkcontainer .checkmark:after {
    left: 5px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 9px;
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that by using datasets.
Every time you check for a list item being hidden you can also check for the dataset values and update them.

Something like this:

```
// check for dataset.country and update dataset.occupation 
var socialToggle = function () {
  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (lis[i].classList.contains('social')) {
      if (lis[i].style.display === 'none' && lis[i].dataset.country !== 'closed') {
        lis[i].style.display = '';
        lis[i].dataset.occupation = 'opened';
      } else {
        lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        lis[i].dataset.occupation = 'closed';
     }
   }
};

// check for dataset.occupation and update dataset.country
var americaToggle = function () {
  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (lis[i].classList.contains('america')) {
      if (lis[i].style.display === 'none' && lis[i].dataset.occupation !== 'closed'){
        lis[i].style.display = '';
        lis[i].dataset.country = 'opened';
      } else {
        lis[i].style.display = 'none';
        lis[i].dataset.country = 'closed';
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT**: working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ypvx9wk4/)

Comment: I am not quite familiar with dataset. Where would the attribute 'closed' or 'opend' come from?

Comment: @manuelJoaquim You can define custom data attributes (data-*) on HTML elements and use dataset property in JavaScript to access those attributes. In this case, you can assign value 'closed' (or whatever you like) to specify the element has been closed previously, and if was, you don't show it.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but how would it be implemented? Something like `data-attr="closed"` inside the link? How can I pass this when the user unchecks something?

Comment: here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcsf76b4/15/). you read and update the dataset values in javascript. If you want to set them initially on your list elements, you can do so by adding `data-country="closed"` attribute. I added that to the last `<li>` tag so that you can see.

Comment: Thank you. I assume the checkbuttons are in charge to change the values? I am very sorry, but I think I need a full working version, the interaction is still confusing to me.

Comment: here's a full working example with comments [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypvx9wk4/)

Comment: Wow, that looks really comprehensive! Just one thing: uglify.js throws an error about `inputs.forEach(input => input` ERROR: Unexpected token: operator (>)

Something to work around?

Comment: it's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). check the docs on Mozilla and you can convert them back to normal functions.

Comment: well, perhaps it is time to move on with uglify and change to babel… works! Thank you very very much!